# Android app random crash in Samsung S4 device when Backpressed or Finish the activity?

Tags: android

android application random crash in Galaxy S4 and Nexus 5. On other device is working file.
The crash happen mostly when I back pressed or finish the activity.

And I got the error in log

```
E/ViewRootImpl( 7168): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
W/ApplicationPackageManager( 7168): getCSCPackageItemText()
W/Resources( 7168): Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0xcd6 "60" a=3 r=0x7f090170}
W/Resources( 7168): Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0xcd5 "500" a=3 r=0x7f09016f}
W/Resources( 7168): Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0xcd7 "30" a=3 r=0x7f090171}
F/libc    ( 7168): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x73880968 passed to dlfree
D/dalvikvm( 7168): [SWE] ### S.LSI JIT optimization list BEGIN ###
D/dalvikvm( 7168): [SWE] ### S.LSI JIT optimization list END ###
F/libc    ( 7168): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 7183 (AsyncTask #1)
D/dalvikvm( 7770): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/dalvikvm( 7770): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
```

can any one help me on this issue , how to resolve or any workaround ...

Comment: A complete log cat would be useful.

Comment: I meant the complete log of the crash. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056506/nullpointerexception-in-my-asynctask. Start from FATAL EXCEPTION

Comment: @DrkStr This is a heap corruption issue (`0xdeadbaad` singals a low level abort), so it's unlikely to have a Java stack trace in the log. Are you using native code somewhere?

Comment: no, I do not use any native code ...

Comment: @DrkStr there is not exceptions display in log...log contain this only doubtfull line..

Comment: how can I fix this heap corruption issue ?